# Parallel mapping over vectors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, vector, parallel-processing

I want a function that does for vectors what `parMap rpar` does for lists. Here's what I've got:

```
import Data.Vector
import Control.Parallel.Strategies

parMapVec :: (a -> b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
parMapVec f = map (runEval . rpar . f)
```

I can't fully reason out how or why this will or won't work.

Another solution might be to make `Vector` an instance of `Traversable` and then use `parTraversable`, but that seems like a lot of work just to get something like `parMap rpar`.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work here? Is there an error? If so please write it here.

Comment: Consider using the [vector strategies](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-strategies-0.4/docs/Data-Vector-Strategies.html) package.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Why is there a need for a package here? The package has exactly one function, whose body is one line long...

Comment: @Alec The need for a package is because the question comes up.  I'm not saying the question shouldn't come up - it's a great question - but if people want to get something that works and delay understanding for another day then the package helps.

Comment: @Alec wow, the implementation of `parVector` is rather dumb. But I think this could be improved to something that makes proper use of the tight array structure. `parMapVec` could actually also be done on unboxed vectors, though I'm not sure if it would require manual concurrency juggling, perhaps `unsafeDupablePerformIO`.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson have you checked that converting to and from a list actually gives sensible performance? I doubt it is acceptable, unless the computation time is completely dominated by the calculations for the individual elements (but in that case, you could just as well simply _work with lists_, rather than vectors).

Comment: It was sensible for a target benchmark when I made it.  Patches welcome!

Comment: Am I being stupid, or is `Vector` from `vector` already a `Traversable`? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#control.i:id:Vector:Traversable:5

Comment: @lierdakil It's not you. Boxed vectors are traversable so for this question a parallel traversable strategy should work fine. Sometimes people want API's that work over all instances of `Data.Vector.Generic.Vector`, which would require something different.

Answer (score 2):

`Vector` is indeed an instance of `Taversable`, as pointed out by lierdakil. I thought that it wasn't because it isn't listed as an instance on the [Data.Traversable page.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#t:Traversable)

Knowing this, I ran some tests:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Maybe

parMapVec :: (a -> b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
parMapVec f v = runEval $ evalTraversable rpar $ V.map f v

range :: Integer -> Integer -> Vector Integer
range x y
  | x == y = x `cons` empty
  | x < y  = x `cons` (range (x + 1) y)
  | x > y  = (range x (y + 1)) `snoc` y

fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac n
  | n < 2     = 1
  | otherwise = n * (fac $ n - 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let result = runEval $ do
        let calc = parMapVec fac $ 80000 `range` 80007
        rseq calc
        return calc
  putStrLn $ show result
```

I compiled this with `ghc --make ParVectorTest.hs -threaded -rtsopts` and ran it with `./ParVectorTest -s` and found that

```
SPARKS: 8 (7 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 1 fizzled)

INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
MUT     time    5.460s  (  5.447s elapsed)
GC      time   15.916s  ( 15.893s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
Total   time   21.380s  ( 21.342s elapsed)
```

Which is good, except that I watched the process execute on my system monitor and saw that the cores were, instead of all calculating a factorial at the same time, trading off between computations.

This is concerning, so I did a test where `main` was modified in the following way:

```
main = do
  let result = runEval $ do
        let calc = parMap rpar fac [80000..80007]
        rseq calc
        return calc
  putStrLn $ show result
```

I compiled and ran in the same way to find that:

```
SPARKS: 16 (14 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 1 GC'd, 1 fizzled)

INIT    time    0.001s  (  0.001s elapsed)
MUT     time    5.412s  (  5.418s elapsed)
GC      time   18.583s  ( 18.537s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.000s elapsed)
Total   time   23.999s  ( 23.957s elapsed)
```

I'm not sure why there are were 16 sparks instead of 8, but I suppose that's besides the point. This version also demonstrated the same behavior of the computation being passed between processors instead of actually being performed in parallel.

So, I've got a version of `parMap rpar` for vectors that is slightly faster, although the fact that neither the program using lists nor the one using vectors fully ran in parallel is concerning.

EDIT: I should add that I ran the same test using my original version of `parMapVec` and all the sparks fizzled, although I can't explain why.